# SOAP Handler not invoked

Tags: java, soap

I have the following Web services.

```html
@WebService(targetNamespace="T24WebServicesImpl")
@XmlSeeAlso( { 
       MYCUSTOMERType.class,
  Object[].class } )
@HandlerChain(file = "./handler-chain.xml") 
public class T24WebServicesImpl extends TwsController {

 @WebMethod
 public void myCustomer(
  .......
 }

}

handler-chain.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxrs:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <jaxrs:handler-chain>
  <jaxrs:handler>
   <jaxrs:handler-class>com.temenos.tws.Handler</jaxrs:handler-class>
  </jaxrs:handler>
 </jaxrs:handler-chain>
</jaxrs:handler-chains>
```

When executing the service, the Handler class is not being invoked.Kindly advise why?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Handler definition like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd">
    <handler-chain>
        <handler>
            <handler-name>Handler</handler-name>
            <handler-class>com.temenos.tws.Handler</handler-class>
        </handler>
    </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

You are using a xml prefix "jaxrs" but you bind the xml defintion to the prefix "javaee". So either change your binding like so `xmlns:jaxrs="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"` or just omit the namespace like shown in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i have omitted the prefix like above, but the response is not calling the Halder again. The handler is supposed to format the returned message into XML, but the following response is still returned.
  <messages>,ResponseCode::ResponseCode/CustomerID::CustomerID/</messages>

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class Handler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

 private byte[] secretBytes;

 /* Getter and Setter methods */
 public Handler() {
 }

 @Override
 public void close(MessageContext mCtx) {
 }

 @Override
 public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext mCtx) {
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext mCtx) {
  
  System.out.println("Server : handleMessage()......");
  Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) mCtx
    .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
  // for response message only, true for outbound messages, false for
  // inbound
  if (isRequest) {

   try {
    SOAPMessage soapMsg = mCtx.getMessage();
    SOAPPart sp = soapMsg.getSOAPPart();
    sp.getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("soap");
    SOAPBody body = soapMsg.getSOAPBody();

    SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(new QName("",
      "javaee"));
    // Test adding a node, restore Arraylist code back
    soapMsg.writeTo(System.out);
    Node testNode = (Node) body.getFirstChild();
    append(testNode, "CustomerName", "Jon Doe");
    
    soapMsg.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println("Server : After append()......");
    
    return true; 
   } catch (Exception ex) {

   }
  }
  return true;
 }

 private void append(Node addNode, String string, String string2) {
  Element element = addNode.getOwnerDocument().createElement(string);
  element.setTextContent(string2);
  addNode.appendChild(element);
 // firstChild.

 }
}
```